# Access to fetch at has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , local API

Tags: php, laravel, cors, fetch

[image]

Access to fetch at `http://user-login.local/` from origin `http://user-login.local` has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

In fact, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header *is* present on my API resource? Here is my API resource, described by cURL/Postman:

```
curl --location 'http://userauthapi.local/api/login' \
--header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' \
--header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST' \
--header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *' \
--form 'email="user@test.com"' \
--form 'password="password"'
```

In short, I'm attempting to login to my API `http://userauthapi.local/api/login` via the fetch object in my front-end app: `http://user-login.local` both on localhost, nginx.

The API is Laravel 10 and is working fine in postman. Here's what I'm trying in Laravel:

**config/cors.php**

```
return [
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*', 'http://user-login.local'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
];
```

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $token = Auth::attempt($credentials);

        if (!$token) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Unauthorized',
            ], 401);
        }

        $user = Auth::user();

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'user' => $user,
            'authorisation' => [
                'token' => $token,
                'type' => 'bearer',
            ]
        ], 200);

    }
```

Also, I try editing the server itself, nginx server block:

```
location / {

    # Simple requests
    if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST)") {
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
    }

    # Preflighted requests
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
      return 200;
    }
}
```

The above is too restrictive it appears and gives me more problems which I have to rewind.

My front-end (http://user-login.local/) is using the js fetch API, like thus:

**/js/login.js**

```
if (error == 0) {
    //do login api here
    var data = {
        username: document.querySelector('#email').value,
        password: document.querySelector('#password').value
    }

    fetch("http://userauthapi.local/api/login", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        header: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((data) => {
            console.error("Error: ", data.message);
        });

    // localStorage.setItem("auth", 1);
    // this.form.submit();
}
```

Any CORS experts out there willing to help? I'm looking to ouput my response data to the console (log) as a check that I can make the circuit from request to response, locally, from my client via my API.

Comment: Why are you leaving out an absolutely essential part of the error message, when you are quoting it in text form? The `(redirected from http://userauthapi.local/api/login)` part is what is causing your issue here. _Why_ is your API redirecting to a completely different system in the first place?

Comment: so, how do we fix it?

Comment: Don't make your API redirect elsewhere, make it give the necessary JSON response directly instead.

Comment: Is this line incorrect? `'allowed_origins' => ['*', 'http://user-login.local'],` ?

Comment: Not necessarily "incorrect", it simply doesn't achieve anything here. This is your CORS configuration on the API side - but since your API _redirects_ to `http://user-login.local/`, your request that was originally started _from_ `http://user-login.local/`, is now also considered cross-origin in its original context. So your application behind `http://user-login.local/` would now also have to allow CORS ... But, again, that doesn't make much sense to begin with. Your API should _not_ be redirecting elsewhere.

Comment: still, non the wiser im afraid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257131/discussion-between-cookie-and-cbroe).

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you, other than to repeat the question: _Why_ is your API redirecting elsewhere to begin with?

Comment: As an aside: `header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' 
--header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST'  --header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *'`  in your cURL request makes no sense. These are headers the server must set, to control CORS requests. The client-side can't meaningfully set them (otherwise CORS would be pointless) and also CORS doesn't apply outside AJAX requests made from browsers. Luckily you haven't replicated the mistake in your JS code.

Comment: API redirecting? That's the confusing bit. My endpoints return JSON specifically? It's not like I make a call to `header()` say?