# How can I resolve the CORS issue and consume the Laravel API using Fetch API for user authentication?

Tags: laravel, rest, fetch-api

Assume I have the following Laravel endpoint  API resource which may be reached here:

```
curl --location 'http://userauthapi.local/api/login' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "email":"my@test.com",
    "password":"password"
}'
```

**/api/login**

```
// app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    $token = Auth::attempt($credentials);
    if (!$token) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => 'Unauthorized',
        ], 401);
    }

    $user = Auth::user();
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'user' => $user,
        'authorisation' => [
            'token' => $token,
            'type' => 'bearer',
        ]
    ], 200);

}
```

So, a basic login method validating a user against the database and returning a JWT token on success. Now, I'm trying to fetch or consume this resource using the Fetch API on the front-end. Here's what I have for that purpose:

```html
<form class="loginForm space-y-4 md:space-y-6" action="" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="••••••••" class="input">
    <button type="submit" class="">Sign in</button>
</form>
</body>
<script defer src="/js/login.js"></script>
</html>
```

**/js/login.js**

```js
class Login {
    constructor(form, fields) {
        this.form = form;
        this.fields = fields;
        this.validationSubmit();
    }

    validationSubmit() {
        let self = this;

        this.form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            var error = 0;
            self.fields.forEach((field) => {
                const input = document.querySelector(`#${field}`);
                if (self.validateField(input) == false) {
                    error++;
                }
            });
            if (error == 0) {
                var data = {
                    username: document.querySelector('#email').value,
                    password: document.querySelector('#password').value
                }

                fetch("//userauthapi.local/api/login", {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                    headers: {
                        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest", <-- edit
                        "Accept": "application/json" <-- edit
                        
                    }
                }).then((response) => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
                    }
                    return response.json();
                }).then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    // Perform further actions based on the response
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
            }
        });


    }

    validateField(field) {
        if (field.value.trim() === "") {
            this.setStatus(
                field,
                `${field.previousElementSibling.innerText} cannot be blank`,
                "error"
            );
            return false;
        } else {
            if (field.type == "password") {
                if (field.value.length < 8) {
                    this.setStatus(
                        field,
                        `${field.previousElementSibling.innerText} must be at least 8 characters`,
                        "error"
                    );
                    return false;
                } else {
                    this.setStatus(field, null, "success");
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                this.setStatus(field, null, "success");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    setStatus(field, message, status) {
        const errorMessage = field.parentElement.querySelector(".error-message");

        if (status == "success") {
            if (errorMessage) {
                errorMessage.innerText = "";
            }
            field.classList.remove("input-error");
        }

        if (status == "error") {
            errorMessage.innerText = message;
            field.classList.add("input-error");
        }
    }
}

const form = document.querySelector(".loginForm");
if (form) {
    const fields = ["email", "password"];
    const validator = new Login(form, fields);
}
```

The problem I have is, upon submitting the form in the browser, I get an error in the console:

> Access to fetch at 'http://user-login.local/' (redirected from 'http://userauthapi.local/api/login') from origin 'http://user-login.local' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

It looks like my API `http://userauthapi.local/api/login` is re-directing for some reason and causing a CORS issue? The API works fine in Postman. Strangely, if I comment out :

```
// $request->validate([
//    'email' => 'required|string|email',
//    'password' => 'required|string',
// ]);
```

The error goes away, but still I can't generate a token even with the correct login credentials?

[image]

My question is then, what's the best way to consume the API using Fetch and leaving the original endpoint the same as it was originally (with `validate()`)?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the issue you already asked about, [Access to fetch at has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , local API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78141006/access-to-fetch-at-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow-ori)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic: _"If validation fails during a traditional HTTP request, a redirect response to the previous URL will be generated. If the incoming request is an XHR request, a JSON response containing the validation error messages will be returned."_ - looks like the system does not recognize that you are making an AJAX request. Probably needs a `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header added to the request.

Comment: And the reason the validation fails to begin with, is that you are trying to validate the presence of two required parameters named `email` and `password` - whereas the parameters you are actually sending with your fetch request, are named `username` and `password`.

Comment: Yeah, when calling `$request->validate()`, it will indeed perform a redirect, unless you're making an AJAX call (which you are, but I think you're just missing the `Accept: application/json` header). You could always try a [Manual Validator](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#manually-creating-validators), and return a JSON response if it fails, but you shouldn't need to.

Comment: Great advice, thanks. I wasn't actually aware I was making an Ajax request.

Comment: Yeah, programatic requests (like JS sending a request to PHP) are XHR/Ajax requests and expect JSON/XML/etc as a response. Navigation in a browser, submitting a form via webpage, etc. are not AJAX requests, and a redirect would be an appropriate response.